# Computer crashed while updating Windows, now Grub Rescue appears on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, grubrescue

Tonight I was installing some updates on Windows 10. My computer just shut down during the installation and when I opened it again, `grub rescue>` appeared. I tried to use `ls` and change the prefix to the right partition, but it says "Filesystem unknown" for all partitions. Also when I run `set`, it says that the root partition is (hd0,msdos6) which does not appear in the list when I run `ls`. It shows only the partitions from 1 to 5.

**I just want to enter Windows**. How to act next?

Comment: You could try [running `boot-repair` from an Ubuntu live USB](http://askubuntu.com/a/182863/301745).

Comment: You've probably been hit by the **Windows 10 Anniversary Update** that wipes out Ubuntu partitions. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD or USB flash key, start gparted, take a screenshot, and edit your question to include the screenshot, and I'll take a look. Cheers, Al